# create multiple folders using existing file names in linux

Tags: bash, pdf, mkdir

i have downloaded several pdf files(with various names) and stored them in a specific directory (for example, `Downloads/directory1`).

i would like to create folders to store these files under the same directory, using the names of the original files, but without the extension pdf.

for example, for a file named `maths.pdf`, i want to create the folder `maths` and store the pdf in it.

i made several attempts creating a script using commands as `basename` and `for`, but i didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
  cd Downloads/directory1
  for f in *.pdf; do
     fname=${echo $f | sed "s/.pdf//" }
     echo "Creating directory [$fname]"
     mkdir "$fname"
  done
```

Comment: Instead of the `sed` pipeline, consider using `basename`.

Comment: The sed pipeline can be used for adapting the name to whatever you need, e.g filename_dir. It's more flexible than basename, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: however, i get several "cannot create directory" errors and the following folders are created instead  | , echo and $f

Comment: I've updated the answer. I forgot an important issue: files might contain spaces. BTW, pay attention to the ` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Assuming you're getting:

```
filename='Downloads/directory1/math.pdf'

f="${filename##*/}"
dir="${f%.*}"

mkdir -p "$dir"
```

will create `math`directory

Comment: although, ia get the following error,syntax erroe near unexpected token 'dir="${f%.*}',
this is my script so far
files='Downloads/directory1/*.pdf'
for f in "${files##*/}"
dir="${f%.*}"
mkdir -p "$dir"
done

Comment: @user2927819: Make sure you're using BASH